# Undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, erb

I am using ERB and creating this DEMO page.
I've tried executing erb this_file.html 
I'm getting the above mentioned error.

Here's my code

```
require 'erb'

def get_items()
   ['bread', 'milk', 'eggs', 'spam']
end

def get_template()
%{
    <DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Shopping List for <%= @date.strftime('%A, %d %B %Y') %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
             <h1>Shopping List for <%= @date.strftime('%A, %d %B %Y') %></h1>
            <p>You need to buy:</p>
            <ul>
              <% for @item in @items %>
                <li><%= h(@item) %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
 }
 end

class ShoppingList
    include ERB::Util
    attr_accessor :items, :template, :date

     def initialize(items, template, date=Time.now)
        @date = date
        @items = items
        @template = template
     end

    def render()
       ERB.new(@template).result(binding)
    end 

    def save(file)
        File.open(file, "w+") do |f|
       f.write(render)
    end
  end

end

list = ShoppingList.new(get_items, get_template)
list.save(File.join(ENV['HOME'], 'list.html'))
```

Comment: I just ran this code and got no error. Can you tell us more? How do you run the code? What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I run the comment:
  $ erb testfile.erb
I'm using **erb.rb [2.1.0 2014-12-12]**

Comment: And testfile.erb contains the code you pasted? This doesn't make much sense. The erb-executable prints the result of compiling a ERB template, but your file is plain ruby file.

Comment: This runs in every version of Ruby I tested, from 1.8.7 through 2.2.1, rbx, jruby, and ree.  The error must be caused by something we can't see here.

Comment: It runs in Ruby.... However i tried to create a template...
running **erb testfile.erb > testfile.erb**  is this not correct should i run **ruby testfile.erb** ??

Comment: Also the code i copied was from this site :
http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/